# Wordpress comments on each users profile page

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, user-profile

I run a wp community site with front-end user registration and user-profile page like mydomain.com/user/username for each user with additional custom fields. Now i need a comment system on it like the wp comments system for post, also with backend function (edit,delete...). The comments system should work exactly the same way as standard WordPress comment system, but instead of posts it should work with users. So other users can comment on users Profile Images or Informations.

I already looked for other similar Questions - but didnt find any solution to achieve this

Any ideas how to achieve this? What should be changed? Is there any wordpress plugin for this or a tutorial?

Thank you so much
best regards

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good solution, 
a bit tricky but it works:

see at: [Comments on user page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/author-page-comments-and-ratings)